# How do I perform a shoryuken motion on the 3DS?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv

I know the shoryuken motion is denoted by the following image:

[image]

My question is, how do I properly input this motion?   I've tried following the z-shaped shape on my Circle Pad but I can never seemingly pull off any Shoryukens at all.  I find that the most common time I've ever pulled one off was randomly mashing buttons and rotating the circle pad. I know that the motion is a Forward, Down, and Forward-Down

Any help here? What's the easiest way to perform one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Forward
- Down
- Down+Forward and Punch simultaneously.

There's also an input shortcut in SF4:

- Down+Forward
- Down+Forward

which will result in the same thing, but is generally less reliable. Turn on 'show input' in training mode to see where you're going wrong.

Comment: THANK YOU.  It seemed like I couldn't get this down consistently, thanks a bunch

Comment: Quick question for @Decency.  I had no problems nailing it down yesterday, but I have the same problems again today.   I've noticed on the Circle Pad on the 3DS that if I slightly tilt the "stick" a little above forward, the character will automatically jump. Is there a way to consistently get this down?

Comment: Just practice. There are a lot of players at the professional level that play on pad, but the majority use a stick for better accuracy. You'll definitely need to avoid moving the stick upward when doing any sort of special motion, though- that's true across the board.

Answer (score 4):

That looks like the symbol for Forward, Down, Foward+Down.

You can see the explanation for these icons [here](http://wiki.shoryuken.com/Super_Street_Fighter_IV/Controls_and_Terminology/Controls) on the Controls page.

Comment: I know what it is, but everytime I go to input the motion, it never performs the action associated with it

Comment: It's probably a timing issue then. I guess you're hitting Punch at the same time as Forward+Down?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I move the circle pad in a forwards, then down towards down, then to forward again, then I press Punch, but no Shoryuken comes out

Comment: Yea, you're probably rotating past forward+down as you head towards down. As @wr4ith said, it's probably the lack of a neutral point between forward and down.

Answer (score 2):

Formally the dragon punch notion is done by executing the following motion:

Forward, neutral, down, down-forward

Note the neutral, this essentially means that you must let go of the joystick for a brief moment before executing the down and down-forward.

Comment: when I go from a down --> down-forward, do I have to push the stick back to neutral then go to forward, or can I do a quarter circle forward following the down?

Comment: No neutral required.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to point out that there are a variety of shortcuts for the DP motion in SSF4.

First, I actually wouldn't recommend the down-forward, down-forward that Decency mentions since it actually relies on doing the motion slightly wrong. You can't do a DP with exactly two joystick motions. Why does it seem to work? It is hard to move straight to down-forward without having it also do forward or down first and that usually gives enough different inputs for it to come out. But if you do down-forward twice perfectly it actually won't work. Experiment in training mode with inputs on and will see what I mean. Having said that, here are some other options:

(Note: while in the normal motion usually you let the joystick go to neutral after the forward, none of the ones below need you go to neutral at any point)

forward, down-forward, forward: That should be a bit easier on a pad and is also helpful if you're already walking forward (just have to slide the joystick down and up slightly). You have to be careful not to go up so far that you jump but it is definitely doable. It is also the version you'd use with Ken to do a kara-dp.

down-forward, down, down-forward: This is IMO the most useful overall. It has the big advantage that you stay crouching throughout the motion. If you're trying to anti-air someone jumping in at you, it gives you more time to react since your body is lower (in older sf games without the shortcut, pro people would whiff a cr.kick so they could do the normal dp motion during the animation without standing the char standing up). It is also good during bnb combos like cr.lk, cr.lp > cr.lp xx h.dp. If you keep the joystick in down-forward as you do the start of the combo, you only have to slide the joystick over to down and back to down-foward and hit punch to cancel into the dp.

down-back, (slide to) down-forward, down, down-forward: If you happen to be crouch blocking already and need to do a dp suddenly, just slide over to down-forward and do the rest of the previous shortcut. It is harder since you have that extra slide motion in there which takes extra time but definitely is doable.

I'd still recommend generally keeping the stick in down-forward during a crouching combo if you're planning to do a dp or tatsu at the end. Feels a bit scary at first but if you drop a link and have hit the next button, they're going to be able to mash-punish as a counter-hit anyway (and if they don't then your moves will start being blocked and you can always move to down-back at that point). For combos that go up and down (say cr.lk, st.lp > cr.mk xx h.dp on Ken), the first part doesn't matter but when you do the cr.mk you should have the stick in down-forward so you can immediately slide over to down, down-foward and hit punch to cancel into a dp.

Answer (score -2):

Press forward, then do the hadoken motion ( down+forward) and punch at the moment you do the motion for hadoken. :)

Comment: This was already mentioned more than 3 years ago.